# SourceTree not using git-ref-format branch name when pushing - is my workaround correct? Is there a better way?

Tags: git, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree

So I appear to be experiencing something similar to this known bug:  https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-8304

It's not exactly the same bug apparently, the symptoms are almost identical, but it doesn't happen when creating a stash, but when pushing to a remote repo, in this case BitBucket.

Now, I'm not terribly well-versed in DVCS stuff, but here's what's happening for me, and my hacky fix that I hope won't bite me in the ass later:

When I press the button to push a commit, I see this dialog, note the overly long branch names:

[image: Push Dialog with Bad Branch Names]

When I hit Push on that dialog, I see this:

[image: Error Message when Pushing]

Then I can go back to the Push dialog and change the branch names like so:

[image: Push Dialog with Fixed Branch Names]

Then when I hit push, I get this success message:

[image: Push Success Message]

So that all LOOKS great, but I want to know if my fix is a good one.  If I accidentally add a typo into one of the branch names, will it break my repo?  Is there a better way to deal with this issue?  Am I creating problems for myself down the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your workaround is correct: you renamed the branch.

> If I accidentally add a typo into one of the branch names, will it break my repo

No, your repository will be fine.
Double-check the status of your repo in command line with a

```
git branch -avv
```

You should not see any other branches with a "long name".

As for stashing, I prefer committing: see "[`git reset --soft` as stash replacement and undo](https://thepugautomatic.com/2009/02/git-reset-soft-as-stash-replacement-and-undo/)": a commit is safer and much harder to lose (compared to a stash pop that goes wrong)

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "stashing".  That link seems to refer to something different to what I'm talking about.  I'm talking about after I've done a commit, I then want to push my changes to the remote repo, in this case bitbucket.  As far as I know this is fairly standard usage.

Comment: Also the main question I asked was "is my workaround correct?", and I'm not sure that you directly answered that.

Comment: I can tell you that "git branch -avv" confirmed that the repo was fine.

Comment: @Excrubulent I was talking about stashing because of your link: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-8304

Comment: @Excrubulent Yes, your workaround is correct: you renamed the branch.

Comment: Oh, I see, well I guess that's a different bug, but it presents almost identically.  Like I said, I'm a bit of a noob and I don't know all the lingo just yet.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the answer, I've just edited your comment into the answer to make it clearer for any future peeps.

Comment: @Excrubulent Thank you. I was actually the one approving your editing 10 hours ago.